# Changing the header of Stackdriver Logging logs in GCP

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am currently working on a GAS project with a lot of `consol.log`, but it's a project which will be deployed.

Is it possible to have a `userName` or a `userMail` in the header of a GCP Stakdriver Logging log entry, next to the date and time?

Here's the part I'm referring to:

[image: 1]

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly modify the header (it will always contain only the timestamp of the log), but you can [add custom fields](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#custom-fields) next to it.

First, you have to include the fields you want to display (`userName` and `userMail`) in your entry log. You can include that in the `jsonPayload` field of the log entry (see the docs of [Structured Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging)). Once done, assuming that your fields are `jsonPayload.userName` and `jsonPayload.userMail`, you can do the following on Stackdriver Logging page in the Google Console :

- click on *View options* (top-right corner, near *Download logs*)
- choose *Modify custom fields*
- add your fields as custom fields : `jsonPayload.userName,jsonPayload.userMail`

Once refreshed, the web page should display your fields at the right of the timestamp.

Comment: Thank for your answer, can you explain more clearly how to include userName and userMail in the json Payload, I'm blocked on that

Comment: I believe that in GAS, if you write JSON in `console.log`, then Stackdriver will automatically write the content of your JSON in the `jsonPayload` field. So basically you could include anything in it (for example : `console.log({message: "hello", userName: "my_user", userMail: "my_mail"})` will generate a log entry with `jsonPayload` in Stackdriver). Could you try this?

Comment: Yes, but that includes writing it to each console.log of the script and I have a lot. I thought we could automate this ?

Comment: You can create and use everywhere a function like `customLog(message)` that resolves to `console.log({message: message, userName: "my_user", userMail: "my_mail"})`. I don't know if this is possible to override the behavior of `console.log` to avoid replacing all `console.log` calls, and if this is possible, it's probably not a good idea (hidden logic).

Comment: Yes I thought about doing that but I didn't think it was a good idea too, I will try that, thanks for your help